# Trying to manually render Spring MVC view to html. but model data does not populates

Tags: java, spring-mvc

This is how I am trying to achieve:

```
View pdfView = this.viewResolver.resolveViewName("documentTesting", Locale.US);
MockHttpServletResponse mockResp = new MockHttpServletResponse();

model.addAttribute("firstName", firstName);
pdfView.render(model.asMap(), request, mockResp);

String html = mockResp.getContentAsString();
System.out.println("rendered html : " + html);
```

Comment: html does not reflect the data from the model. Please help in this case.

Comment: Resolved! the issue was with the view . Tt was using <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"> which uses specific syntax .